# How can I use Properties.Settings when I deploy my C# Winforms app with NSIS?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings, nsis

I have written a C# app using Winforms, and am trying to utilise the inbuilt Properties.Settings (User scope) to remember user state between launches of the program.
When the app is deployed via Visual Studio's inbuilt **Build** > **Publish**, apparently this file is put into the Local Appdata folder.
However, I want to use NSIS to create the executable of the program. I am able to place the **ProgramName.exe.config** file into Local AppData, via NSIS script, but my app does not seem to read from it. No user settings persist.

Is this even possible? Or should I use my own method (database or write my own settings xml) to store user settings?

Comment: User Settings are not persisted in `.exe.config` (default values are defined there), but in the `user.config` file. Check this: `var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);`. See `config.HasFile` (a file is present) and `config.FilePath` for the path of the file (includes the file name). The path changes depending on the information you have stored in the `Assembly Information` dialog in `Project->Properties->Application` (or manually, in code).

Comment: @Jimi Interesting. I didn't have the System.Configuration reference imported at all. The code referencing ConfigurationManager is also invalid, unless I am in Release mode (not Debug). I am unfamiliar with such behaviour.
The path is: C:\Users\mila\AppData\Local\ProgramName\ProgramName.exe_Url_lsmwr1o5wnkk1e4dsuyvs2totzfyilr4\1.0.0.0\user.config
What does this mean for me when using NSIS to deploy the project? Do I need to fetch this file off my PC and include it in the install?

Comment: Hmmm, I cannot fetch the file because it doesn't exist yet. I guess this is some placeholder whilst running from visual studio. Is there a resource you could perhaps point me to to better understand how this works?

Comment: The reference issue to ConfigurationManager was solved by deleting the reference and importing it again when in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working with NSIS.
The App.config file has a property called "Copy to Output Directory" which was set to "Do not Copy" by default. I found this information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/

I found out where the user.config file was going to be created, with help from @Jimi by adding System.Configuration as a reference, and then getting the path using:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
```

The user.config file is not created on application install, rather the first time that the following is called:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

There is nothing special that the developer has to do in NSIS.